# Nested array in for each loop

Tags: php, arrays

Afternoon all,

I am having a few more issues. I have a nested array, I think that's what it is called, shown below.

```
Array ( 
[Material] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Material [1] => 3 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Material [1] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Material [1] => 4 ) ) 
[Base] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Base [1] => 2 ) ) )
```

I am wanting to use this to create a foreach loop to use in PHP. I need to have an iteration  for 'Material' and another for 'Base'. There may be more in the future. I'm then wanting to use the array values (3, 1, 4) for example to create a filter for a SQL query using the code below.

```
$brand_filter = implode("','", *Array values here*);
```

How would I go about this? I have looked at some examples on here and have gotten conversion to string errors.

These is the code I am using to test my for each loop

```
foreach ($grouped as $group => $types) {
echo "Group: " . $group;
foreach ($types as $type) {
        echo "Type: " . $type;
     }
}
```

This is the result I am getting

> Group: Material
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\360v3\ext\filter\fetch_data.php
> on line 50
>
> Type: Array

Answer (score 0):

Your error is letting you know that you are trying to concatenate an array to a string.

In your code, `$type` is an array, and will be one of these in order as your loops execute:

```
[0 => Material, 1 => 3]
[0 => Material, 1 => 1]
[0 => Material, 1 => 4]
[0 => Base, 1 => 2]
```

To access the second value you will need to update your code to:

```php
foreach ($grouped as $group => $types) {
    echo "Group: " . $group;
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        echo "Type: " . $type[1];
    }
}
```

Notice the `$type[1]`

This will result in an output of:

```
Group: Material
Type: 3
Type: 1
Type: 4
Group: Base
Type: 2
```